# Copy data from skb to ringbuf

Tags: ebpf, bpf, libbpf

I'm trying to detect incoming ELF file downloads and copy them to a userspace program. I want to achieve this by using ringbuffer map and copy the data from the skb struct to the memory space allocated in the ringbuf map. The userspace program handles the submitted data and for now it just prints it.

My current solution fails on the line where I try to copy the TCP payload from the skb to a reserved space in the ringbuffer. I can't convince the verifier that the memory where I want to copy is valid.

The error I get:

```
invalid access to memory, mem_size=1528 off=0 size=0
R3 min value is outside of the allowed memory range
```

I'm running my eBPF code as a modified version of the `sockfilter.bpf.c` file from the [libbpf-bootstrap repo](https://github.com/libbpf/libbpf-bootstrap), with the default build steps. I'm running this on `Linux debian 6.1.0-10-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.37-1 (2023-07-03) x86_64 GNU/Linux`.

This is my eBPF code:

```c
#include <stddef.h>
#include <linux/bpf.h>
#include <linux/if_ether.h>
#include <linux/ip.h>
#include <linux/in.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_helpers.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_endian.h>
#include "sockfilter.h"

#define MAGIC_NUMBER     0x7F454C46
#define IP_MF        0x2000
#define IP_OFFSET    0x1FFF
#define TRACKED_MAX_SIZE 15000

char LICENSE[] SEC("license") = "Dual BSD/GPL";

struct {
    __uint(type, BPF_MAP_TYPE_HASH);
    __uint(max_entries, 256);
    __type(key, __u64);
    __type(value, __u32);
} downloads SEC(".maps");

struct {
    __uint(type, BPF_MAP_TYPE_RINGBUF);
    __uint(max_entries, 32 * sizeof(struct filter_event));
} rb SEC(".maps");

...

SEC("socket")
int socket_handler(struct __sk_buff *skb)
{
    struct filter_event *e;
    // Ip Header OFFset
    __u32 ihoff = ETH_HLEN;
    // Tcp Header OFFset
    __u32 thoff;
    // Network Header OFFset
    __u32 nhoff;

    __u32 dst_ip;
    __u16 dst_port;

    __u32 start = 0;
    __u64 tracked_len = 0;

    if (!is_ip(skb))
        return 0;

    bpf_skb_load_bytes(skb, ihoff + offsetof(struct iphdr, daddr), &dst_ip, sizeof(dst_ip));

    if (ip_is_fragment(skb, ihoff))
        return 0;

    if (!is_tcp(skb, &thoff))
        return 0;

    bpf_skb_load_bytes(skb, thoff + 2, &dst_port, sizeof(dst_port));

    get_data_offset(skb, thoff, &nhoff);

    if (correct_magic_number(skb, nhoff)) {
        start = 1;
        bpf_printk("Correct magic number!");
    }

    if (!start) {
        __u64 key = dst_ip << 16 & dst_port;

        tracked_len = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&downloads, &key);
    }

    if (!tracked_len && !start) {
        return 0;
    }
    bpf_printk("Interested!");

    /* reserve sample from BPF ringbuf */
    e = bpf_ringbuf_reserve(&rb, sizeof(struct filter_event), 0);
    if (e == NULL) {
        bpf_printk("Unable to reserve size in ringbuf!\n");
        return 0;
    }

    __u32 size = skb->len - nhoff;
    size &= 0xFFFF;
    if (size > TRACKED_MAX_SIZE - tracked_len)
        size = TRACKED_MAX_SIZE - tracked_len;

    // IT FAILS HERE!!!
    if (size < sizeof(e->data) && nhoff + size < skb->len &&
        bpf_skb_load_bytes(skb, nhoff, &(e->data), size)) {
        bpf_ringbuf_discard(e, 0);
        bpf_printk("Unable to read the payload!\n");
        return 0;
    }

    e->len = size;
    e->dst_addr = dst_ip;
    e->dst_port = dst_port;

    bpf_printk("Submitted, len: %d, nhoff: %d, e.len: %d\n", skb->len, nhoff, e->len);
    bpf_ringbuf_submit(e, 0);

    return skb->len;
}
```

The output I get:

```
make sockfilter && sudo ./sockfilter
  BPF      .output/sockfilter.bpf.o
sockfilter.bpf.c:139:15: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to '__u64' (aka 'unsigned long long') from 'void *' [-Wint-conversion]
                tracked_len = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&downloads, &key);
                            ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
  GEN-SKEL .output/sockfilter.skel.h
  CC       .output/sockfilter.o
sockfilter.c: In function ‘handle_event’:
sockfilter.c:132:20: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 3 has type ‘const __u8 (*)[1518]’ {aka ‘const unsigned char (*)[1518]’} [-Wformat=]
  132 |         printf("%.*s\n", e->len, &(e->data));
      |                 ~~~^             ~~~~~~~~~~
      |                    |             |
      |                    char *        const __u8 (*)[1518] {aka const unsigned char (*)[1518]}
sockfilter.c: At top level:
sockfilter.c:65:20: warning: ‘ipproto_mapping’ defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
   65 | static const char *ipproto_mapping[IPPROTO_MAX] = {
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  BINARY   sockfilter
libbpf: loading object 'sockfilter_bpf' from buffer
libbpf: elf: section(2) .symtab, size 528, link 1, flags 0, type=2
libbpf: elf: section(3) socket, size 1232, link 0, flags 6, type=1
libbpf: sec 'socket': found program 'socket_handler' at insn offset 0 (0 bytes), code size 154 insns (1232 bytes)
libbpf: elf: section(4) license, size 13, link 0, flags 3, type=1
libbpf: license of sockfilter_bpf is Dual BSD/GPL
libbpf: elf: section(5) .rodata, size 141, link 0, flags 2, type=1
libbpf: elf: section(6) .maps, size 48, link 0, flags 3, type=1
libbpf: elf: section(7) .relsocket, size 112, link 2, flags 40, type=9
libbpf: elf: section(8) .BTF, size 3871, link 0, flags 0, type=1
libbpf: elf: section(9) .BTF.ext, size 1088, link 0, flags 0, type=1
libbpf: looking for externs among 22 symbols...
libbpf: collected 0 externs total
libbpf: map 'downloads': at sec_idx 6, offset 0.
libbpf: map 'downloads': found type = 1.
libbpf: map 'downloads': found key [8], sz = 8.
libbpf: map 'downloads': found value [11], sz = 4.
libbpf: map 'downloads': found max_entries = 256.
libbpf: map 'rb': at sec_idx 6, offset 32.
libbpf: map 'rb': found type = 27.
libbpf: map 'rb': found max_entries = 48896.
libbpf: map 'sockfilt.rodata' (global data): at sec_idx 5, offset 0, flags 80.
libbpf: map 2 is "sockfilt.rodata"
libbpf: sec '.relsocket': collecting relocation for section(3) 'socket'
libbpf: sec '.relsocket': relo #0: insn #69 against '.rodata'
libbpf: prog 'socket_handler': found data map 2 (sockfilt.rodata, sec 5, off 0) for insn 69
libbpf: sec '.relsocket': relo #1: insn #79 against 'downloads'
libbpf: prog 'socket_handler': found map 0 (downloads, sec 6, off 0) for insn #79
libbpf: sec '.relsocket': relo #2: insn #85 against '.rodata'
libbpf: prog 'socket_handler': found data map 2 (sockfilt.rodata, sec 5, off 0) for insn 85
libbpf: sec '.relsocket': relo #3: insn #90 against 'rb'
libbpf: prog 'socket_handler': found map 1 (rb, sec 6, off 32) for insn #90
libbpf: sec '.relsocket': relo #4: insn #97 against '.rodata'
libbpf: prog 'socket_handler': found data map 2 (sockfilt.rodata, sec 5, off 0) for insn 97
libbpf: sec '.relsocket': relo #5: insn #133 against '.rodata'
libbpf: prog 'socket_handler': found data map 2 (sockfilt.rodata, sec 5, off 0) for insn 133
libbpf: sec '.relsocket': relo #6: insn #148 against '.rodata'
libbpf: prog 'socket_handler': found data map 2 (sockfilt.rodata, sec 5, off 0) for insn 148
libbpf: map 'downloads': created successfully, fd=4
libbpf: map 'rb': created successfully, fd=5
libbpf: map 'sockfilt.rodata': created successfully, fd=6
libbpf: prog 'socket_handler': BPF program load failed: Permission denied
libbpf: prog 'socket_handler': -- BEGIN PROG LOAD LOG --

...

; if (correct_magic_number(skb, nhoff)) {
68: (55) if r9 != 0x464c457f goto pc+6        ; R9_w=1179403647
; bpf_printk("Correct magic number!");
69: (18) r1 = 0xffff8d7f062f4b10      ; R1_w=map_value(off=0,ks=4,vs=141,imm=0)
71: (b7) r2 = 22                      ; R2_w=22
72: (85) call bpf_trace_printk#6      ; R0_w=scalar()
73: (b7) r0 = 0                       ; R0_w=0
74: (05) goto pc+9
; if (!tracked_len && !start) {
84: (7b) *(u64 *)(r10 -24) = r0       ; R0_w=P0 R10=fp0 fp-24_w=00000000
; bpf_printk("Interested!");
85: (18) r1 = 0xffff8d7f062f4b26      ; R1_w=map_value(off=22,ks=4,vs=141,imm=0)
87: (b7) r2 = 12                      ; R2_w=12
88: (85) call bpf_trace_printk#6      ; R0=scalar()
89: (b7) r8 = 0                       ; R8_w=0
; e = bpf_ringbuf_reserve(&rb, sizeof(struct filter_event), 0);
90: (18) r1 = 0xffff8d7f062f4600      ; R1_w=map_ptr(off=0,ks=0,vs=0,imm=0)
92: (b7) r2 = 1528                    ; R2_w=1528
93: (b7) r3 = 0                       ; R3_w=0
94: (85) call bpf_ringbuf_reserve#131         ; R0_w=alloc_mem_or_null(id=5,ref_obj_id=5,off=0,imm=0) refs=5
95: (bf) r9 = r0                      ; R0_w=alloc_mem_or_null(id=5,ref_obj_id=5,off=0,imm=0) R9_w=alloc_mem_or_null(id=5,ref_obj_id=5,off=0,imm=0) refs=5
; if (e == NULL) {
96: (55) if r9 != 0x0 goto pc+4 101: R0_w=alloc_mem(ref_obj_id=5,off=0,imm=0) R6=ctx(off=0,imm=0) R7=scalar(id=3,umin=14,umax=134,var_off=(0x2; 0xfc)) R8_w=0 R9_w=alloc_mem(ref_obj_id=5,off=0,imm=0) R10=fp0 fp-8=mmmmmm?? fp-16=????mmmm fp-24=00000000 refs=5
; bpf_printk("Unable to reserve size in ringbuf!\n");
101: (b7) r8 = 15000                  ; R8_w=15000 refs=5
; if (size > TRACKED_MAX_SIZE - tracked_len)
102: (79) r1 = *(u64 *)(r10 -24)      ; R1_w=P0 R10=fp0 refs=5
103: (1f) r8 -= r1                    ; R1_w=P0 R8_w=15000 refs=5
; __u32 size = skb->len - nhoff;
104: (61) r3 = *(u32 *)(r6 +0)        ; R3_w=scalar(umax=4294967295,var_off=(0x0; 0xffffffff)) R6=ctx(off=0,imm=0) refs=5
; __u32 size = skb->len - nhoff;
105: (bf) r1 = r3                     ; R1_w=scalar(id=6,umax=4294967295,var_off=(0x0; 0xffffffff)) R3_w=scalar(id=6,umax=4294967295,var_off=(0x0; 0xffffffff)) refs=5
106: (1f) r1 -= r7                    ; R1_w=scalar(smin=-134,smax=4294967281) R7=scalar(id=3,umin=14,umax=134,var_off=(0x2; 0xfc)) refs=5
; size &= 0xFFFF;
107: (57) r1 &= 65535                 ; R1_w=scalar(umax=65535,var_off=(0x0; 0xffff)) refs=5
; if (size > TRACKED_MAX_SIZE - tracked_len)
108: (2d) if r1 > r8 goto pc+1        ; R1_w=scalar(umax=15000,var_off=(0x0; 0x3fff)) R8_w=15000 refs=5
109: (bf) r8 = r1                     ; R1=scalar(id=7,umax=15000,var_off=(0x0; 0x3fff)) R8=scalar(id=7,umax=15000,var_off=(0x0; 0x3fff)) refs=5
110: (bf) r1 = r8                     ; R1_w=scalar(id=7,umax=15000,var_off=(0x0; 0x3fff)) R8=scalar(id=7,umax=15000,var_off=(0x0; 0x3fff)) refs=5
111: (67) r1 <<= 32                   ; R1_w=scalar(umax=64424509440000,var_off=(0x0; 0x3fff00000000),s32_max=0,u32_max=0) refs=5
112: (77) r1 >>= 32                   ; R1_w=scalar(umax=15000,var_off=(0x0; 0x3fff),s32_max=16383,u32_max=16383) refs=5
; if (size < sizeof(e->data) && nhoff + size < skb->len &&
113: (25) if r1 > 0x5ed goto pc+13    ; R1_w=scalar(umax=1517,var_off=(0x0; 0x7ff)) refs=5
114: (bf) r1 = r8                     ; R1_w=scalar(id=7,umax=15000,var_off=(0x0; 0x3fff)) R8=scalar(id=7,umax=15000,var_off=(0x0; 0x3fff)) refs=5
115: (0f) r1 += r7                    ; R1_w=scalar(umin=14,umax=15134,var_off=(0x0; 0x3fff)) R7=scalar(id=3,umin=14,umax=134,var_off=(0x2; 0xfc)) refs=5
116: (bf) r2 = r3                     ; R2_w=scalar(id=6,umax=4294967295,var_off=(0x0; 0xffffffff)) R3=scalar(id=6,umax=4294967295,var_off=(0x0; 0xffffffff)) refs=5
117: (67) r1 <<= 32                   ; R1_w=scalar(umin=60129542144,umax=65000035057664,var_off=(0x0; 0x3fff00000000),s32_min=0,s32_max=0,u32_max=0) refs=5
118: (77) r1 >>= 32                   ; R1_w=scalar(umin=14,umax=15134,var_off=(0x0; 0x3fff),s32_min=0,s32_max=16383,u32_max=16383) refs=5
119: (3d) if r1 >= r2 goto pc+7       ; R1_w=scalar(umin=14,umax=15134,var_off=(0x0; 0x3fff),s32_min=0,s32_max=16383,u32_max=16383) R2_w=scalar(id=6,umax=4294967295,var_off=(0x0; 0xffffffff)) refs=5
; bpf_skb_load_bytes(skb, nhoff, &(e->data), size)) {
120: (bf) r1 = r6                     ; R1_w=ctx(off=0,imm=0) R6=ctx(off=0,imm=0) refs=5
121: (bf) r2 = r7                     ; R2_w=scalar(id=3,umin=14,umax=134,var_off=(0x2; 0xfc)) R7=scalar(id=3,umin=14,umax=134,var_off=(0x2; 0xfc)) refs=5
122: (bf) r3 = r9                     ; R3_w=alloc_mem(ref_obj_id=5,off=0,imm=0) R9=alloc_mem(ref_obj_id=5,off=0,imm=0) refs=5
123: (bf) r4 = r8                     ; R4_w=scalar(id=7,umax=15000,var_off=(0x0; 0x3fff)) R8=scalar(id=7,umax=15000,var_off=(0x0; 0x3fff)) refs=5
124: (85) call bpf_skb_load_bytes#26
invalid access to memory, mem_size=1528 off=0 size=0
R3 min value is outside of the allowed memory range
processed 116 insns (limit 1000000) max_states_per_insn 0 total_states 8 peak_states 8 mark_read 3
-- END PROG LOAD LOG --
libbpf: prog 'socket_handler': failed to load: -13
libbpf: failed to load object 'sockfilter_bpf'
libbpf: failed to load BPF skeleton 'sockfilter_bpf': -13
Failed to open and load BPF skeleton
```

I also tried to copy the whole data from the skb to a local buffer and use `bpf_ringbuf_output` to pass the data from the local buffer to the userspace program.

With this approach I get:

```
invalid access to map value, value_size=1518 off=0 size=0
R3 min value is outside of the allowed memory range
```

This is the local buffer code:

```c
#include <stddef.h>
#include <linux/bpf.h>
#include <linux/if_ether.h>
#include <linux/ip.h>
#include <linux/in.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_helpers.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_endian.h>

#define MAGIC_NUMBER     0x7F454C46
#define IP_MF        0x2000
#define IP_OFFSET    0x1FFF
#define TRACKED_MAX_SIZE 15000
#define BUFFSIZE     1518

char LICENSE[] SEC("license") = "Dual BSD/GPL";

__u8 buf[BUFFSIZE];

...

SEC("socket")
int socket_handler(struct __sk_buff *skb)
{
    struct filter_event *e;
    // Ip Header OFFset
    __u32 ihoff = ETH_HLEN;
    // Tcp Header OFFset
    __u32 thoff;
    // Network Header OFFset
    __u32 nhoff;

    __u32 dst_ip;
    __u16 dst_port;

    __u32 start = 0;
    __u64 tracked_len = 0;

    if (!is_ip(skb))
        return 0;

    bpf_skb_load_bytes(skb, ihoff + offsetof(struct iphdr, daddr), &dst_ip, sizeof(dst_ip));

    if (ip_is_fragment(skb, ihoff))
        return 0;

    if (!is_tcp(skb, &thoff))
        return 0;

    bpf_skb_load_bytes(skb, thoff + 2, &dst_port, sizeof(dst_port));

    get_data_offset(skb, thoff, &nhoff);

    if (correct_magic_number(skb, nhoff)) {
        start = 1;
        bpf_printk("Correct magic number!");
    }

    if (!start) {
        __u64 key = dst_ip << 16 & dst_port;

        tracked_len = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&downloads, &key);
    }

    if (!tracked_len && !start) {
        return 0;
    }
    bpf_printk("Interested!");

    // IT FAILS HERE!!!
    if (bpf_skb_load_bytes(skb, 0, buf, skb->len)) {
        bpf_printk("Unable to read the payload!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    bpf_ringbuf_output(&rb, buf, skb->len, 0);

    bpf_printk("Submitted, len: %d\n", skb->len);
    bpf_ringbuf_submit(e, 0);

    return skb->len;
}
```

And this is the output I get when I use the local buffer:

```
make sockfilter && sudo ./sockfilter
  BPF      .output/sockfilter.bpf.o
sockfilter.bpf.c:141:15: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to '__u64' (aka 'unsigned long long') from 'void *' [-Wint-conversion]
                tracked_len = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&downloads, &key);
                            ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
  GEN-SKEL .output/sockfilter.skel.h
  CC       .output/sockfilter.o
sockfilter.c: In function ‘handle_event’:
sockfilter.c:132:20: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 3 has type ‘const __u8 (*)[1518]’ {aka ‘const unsigned char (*)[1518]’} [-Wformat=]
  132 |         printf("%.*s\n", e->len, &(e->data));
      |                 ~~~^             ~~~~~~~~~~
      |                    |             |
      |                    char *        const __u8 (*)[1518] {aka const unsigned char (*)[1518]}
sockfilter.c: At top level:
sockfilter.c:65:20: warning: ‘ipproto_mapping’ defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
   65 | static const char *ipproto_mapping[IPPROTO_MAX] = {
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  BINARY   sockfilter
[sudo] password for vboxuser: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for vboxuser: 
libbpf: loading object 'sockfilter_bpf' from buffer
libbpf: elf: section(2) .symtab, size 432, link 1, flags 0, type=2
libbpf: elf: section(3) socket, size 928, link 0, flags 6, type=1
libbpf: sec 'socket': found program 'socket_handler' at insn offset 0 (0 bytes), code size 116 insns (928 bytes)
libbpf: elf: section(4) license, size 13, link 0, flags 3, type=1
libbpf: license of sockfilter_bpf is Dual BSD/GPL
libbpf: elf: section(5) .rodata, size 83, link 0, flags 2, type=1
libbpf: elf: section(6) .maps, size 48, link 0, flags 3, type=1
libbpf: elf: section(7) .bss, size 1518, link 0, flags 3, type=8
libbpf: elf: section(8) .relsocket, size 128, link 2, flags 40, type=9
libbpf: elf: section(9) .BTF, size 3488, link 0, flags 0, type=1
libbpf: elf: section(10) .BTF.ext, size 848, link 0, flags 0, type=1
libbpf: looking for externs among 18 symbols...
libbpf: collected 0 externs total
libbpf: map 'downloads': at sec_idx 6, offset 0.
libbpf: map 'downloads': found type = 1.
libbpf: map 'downloads': found key [8], sz = 8.
libbpf: map 'downloads': found value [11], sz = 4.
libbpf: map 'downloads': found max_entries = 256.
libbpf: map 'rb': at sec_idx 6, offset 32.
libbpf: map 'rb': found type = 27.
libbpf: map 'rb': found max_entries = 48576.
libbpf: map 'sockfilt.rodata' (global data): at sec_idx 5, offset 0, flags 80.
libbpf: map 2 is "sockfilt.rodata"
libbpf: map 'sockfilt.bss' (global data): at sec_idx 7, offset 0, flags 400.
libbpf: map 3 is "sockfilt.bss"
libbpf: sec '.relsocket': collecting relocation for section(3) 'socket'
libbpf: sec '.relsocket': relo #0: insn #69 against '.rodata'
libbpf: prog 'socket_handler': found data map 2 (sockfilt.rodata, sec 5, off 0) for insn 69
libbpf: sec '.relsocket': relo #1: insn #78 against 'downloads'
libbpf: prog 'socket_handler': found map 0 (downloads, sec 6, off 0) for insn #78
libbpf: sec '.relsocket': relo #2: insn #82 against '.rodata'
libbpf: prog 'socket_handler': found data map 2 (sockfilt.rodata, sec 5, off 0) for insn 82
libbpf: sec '.relsocket': relo #3: insn #90 against 'buf'
libbpf: prog 'socket_handler': found data map 3 (sockfilt.bss, sec 7, off 0) for insn 90
libbpf: sec '.relsocket': relo #4: insn #94 against '.rodata'
libbpf: prog 'socket_handler': found data map 2 (sockfilt.rodata, sec 5, off 0) for insn 94
libbpf: sec '.relsocket': relo #5: insn #100 against 'rb'
libbpf: prog 'socket_handler': found map 1 (rb, sec 6, off 32) for insn #100
libbpf: sec '.relsocket': relo #6: insn #102 against 'buf'
libbpf: prog 'socket_handler': found data map 3 (sockfilt.bss, sec 7, off 0) for insn 102
libbpf: sec '.relsocket': relo #7: insn #107 against '.rodata'
libbpf: prog 'socket_handler': found data map 2 (sockfilt.rodata, sec 5, off 0) for insn 107
libbpf: map 'downloads': created successfully, fd=4
libbpf: map 'rb': created successfully, fd=5
libbpf: map 'sockfilt.rodata': created successfully, fd=6
libbpf: map 'sockfilt.bss': created successfully, fd=7
libbpf: prog 'socket_handler': BPF program load failed: Permission denied
libbpf: prog 'socket_handler': -- BEGIN PROG LOAD LOG --

...

; if (correct_magic_number(skb, nhoff)) {
68: (55) if r1 != 0x464c457f goto pc+5        ; R1_w=1179403647
; bpf_printk("Correct magic number!");
69: (18) r1 = 0xffff8d7f062f5b10      ; R1_w=map_value(off=0,ks=4,vs=83,imm=0)
71: (b7) r2 = 22                      ; R2_w=22
72: (85) call bpf_trace_printk#6      ; R0_w=scalar()
73: (05) goto pc+8
; bpf_printk("Interested!");
82: (18) r1 = 0xffff8d7f062f5b26      ; R1_w=map_value(off=22,ks=4,vs=83,imm=0)
84: (b7) r2 = 12                      ; R2_w=12
85: (85) call bpf_trace_printk#6      ; R0=scalar()
; if (bpf_skb_load_bytes(skb, 0, buf, skb->len)) {
86: (61) r4 = *(u32 *)(r6 +0)         ; R4_w=scalar(umax=4294967295,var_off=(0x0; 0xffffffff)) R6=ctx(off=0,imm=0)
87: (b7) r7 = 0                       ; R7_w=0
88: (bf) r1 = r6                      ; R1_w=ctx(off=0,imm=0) R6=ctx(off=0,imm=0)
89: (b7) r2 = 0                       ; R2_w=0
90: (18) r3 = 0xffffb73b40468000      ; R3_w=map_value(off=0,ks=4,vs=1518,imm=0)
92: (85) call bpf_skb_load_bytes#26
invalid access to map value, value_size=1518 off=0 size=0
R3 min value is outside of the allowed memory range
processed 84 insns (limit 1000000) max_states_per_insn 0 total_states 6 peak_states 6 mark_read 3
-- END PROG LOAD LOG --
libbpf: prog 'socket_handler': failed to load: -13
libbpf: failed to load object 'sockfilter_bpf'
libbpf: failed to load BPF skeleton 'sockfilter_bpf': -13
Failed to open and load BPF skeleton
```

It seems like the verifier looses track of the minimum value of the memory addreses. In the second approach the address of the local buffer is a constant but I still get a min value error.

If I'm correct the first solution would be more performant, but I'm not really sure. Sorry if I missed some obvious step, this would be my first project using eBPF.

========================================

**Edit:**

This is the structure of filter_event:

```c
struct filter_event {
    __u8 data[TRACKED_MAX_SIZE];
    __be32 dst_addr;
    __be16 dst_port;
    __be16 len;
}
```

I tried to make the data buffer bigger, but the mem_size in the error just increased by the same amount. I'm not sure, why it is trying to write more data into the buffer than it should, as the size is maximized at 15000 bytes.

Comment: Could you share the definition of `struct filter_event`? The verifier is basically saying that is too small to hold the data.

Comment: Thanks, I added the struct definition.